# Cannot create ExtentReport for Selenium 3.5.1

Tags: selenium

I have tried with almost all jar files with extentreport from 2.41.2 to 
       3.13.0 but whenever I try to write the command: extent.loadConfig(new 
       File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//ReportsConfig.xml")); it throws error on multiple lines but for instance i have put up one example 
       showing as "The method loadConfig(File) is undefined for the type 
       ExtentReports".

```
   My code for ExtentReport Class is `enter code here`:
   package TestNG_package;


   import java.io.File;
   import java.util.Date;

   import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.AbstractReporter;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;


   public class ExtentManager 
   {
       private static ExtentReports extent;
       public static String screenshotFolderPath;
       static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;

       public static ExtentReports getInstance()
       {
           if (extent == null)
           {

               extent = new 
   ExtentReport("E:\\Selenium\\Workspace\\New_Test\\test-output\\report.html");
               extent.loadConfig(new 
   File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//ReportsConfig.xml"));
               extent.addSystemInfo("Selenium ver" , 
   "3.5.1").addSystemInfo("Environ" , "PROD");
           }

           return extent;
       }


   }


   My next part of code is to invoke ExtentReport in other class called 
   loginTest
   public class LoginTest()
   {
       @Test
       public void doLogin()
       {
           ExtentReport rep = ExtentManager.getInstance();
           ExtentTest Test = rep.startTest("UATRMS start");
           Test.log(LogStatus.Info,"Starting UATRMS Test");
           rep.endTest(test);
           rep.flush();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is

```
reporter.loadXMLConfig("extent-config.xml");
```

The method you are using is for instances where you have a properties file. See the docs for more info.  This method is used by the reporter, not the core API.  Reporters can be configured using these configuration items.

Comment: is it reporter or htmlreporter?  even if i do in my other class LoginTest, it throws error for the lines ExtentTest Test = rep.startTest("UATRMS start");
           Test.log(LogStatus.Info,"Starting UATRMS Test");
           rep.endTest(test);

Comment: I want to know if its a problem with my jar files.

Comment: Config is loaded by your reporters, HTMLReporter in this case.

Comment: Could you please help me out with the codes in the main class then? I mean codes for starting the reporting test till ending it.